# React dev tools add is showing the html tags instead of the component tag

Tags: reactjs

hello react dev tools is shows the html tags instead of the component tag

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The react dev tools will signify the component themselves based on its name, in your case the minified name, and they are purple in color. The HTML that the component renders is signified as gray which is what you are seeing. If you look above `<table>` you will see  `<t rows[{ ...>` and that is the actual react component.

here is an example:
[image]

the component is `PageHeader` it renders various divs and html which are gray and also a `Tooltip` component that you can see has its component name and props. If you expanded `Tooltip` you would see the HTML or components that it renders.